# BSOD error - minidump file not definitive

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, bsod

I've been getting tons of BSOD errors over the last couple of weeks. At the bottom of this post I put the most recent three dump files (only ones I have). Yesterday I re-installed Windows from scratch, wiping my hard drive. That did not fix the problem; shortly after, I got a blue screen while trying to download Steam.

Today I removed my graphics card to see if my graphics card was failing, and I'm now running on my motherboard's built-in graphics. I got another BSOD while just using Chrome. Any advice what it could be please?

```
2: kd> !analyze -v

*
Bugcheck Analysis *
*
BAD_POOL_HEADER (19) The pool is already corrupt at the time of the current request. This may or may not be due to the caller. The internal pool links must be walked to figure out a possible cause of the problem, and then special pool applied to the suspect tags or the driver verifier to a suspect driver. Arguments: Arg1: 0000000000000003, the pool freelist is corrupt. Arg2: fffff8a005df4b40, the pool entry being checked. Arg3: fffff8a005df4b40, the read back flink freelist value (should be the same as 2). Arg4: fdfff8a005df4b40, the read back blink freelist value (should be the same as 2).

Debugging Details:

BUGCHECK_STR: 0x19_3

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT: 1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID: VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME: svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL: 0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER: from fffff800029f410b to fffff800028c2f00

STACK_TEXT:
fffff88006275998 fffff800029f410b : 0000000000000019 0000000000000003 fffff8a005df4b40 fffff8a005df4b40 : nt!KeBugCheckEx fffff880062759a0 fffff800029f64c1 : fffffa80056de530 fffff8a005e96000 fffffa8005575168 0000000000000000 : nt!ExFreePool+0x75b fffff88006275a30 fffff800028c80bc : fffff8a005e96030 0000000000000000 fffffa80656b6f54 fffffa8004e86f30 : nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x411 fffff88006275ae0 fffff80002bd6194 : fffffa80072d6b30 0000000000000000 fffffa8005575060 0000000000000000 : nt!ObfDereferenceObject+0xdc fffff88006275b40 fffff80002bd6094 : 00000000000007f8 fffffa80072d6b30 fffff8a001847b40 00000000000007f8 : nt!ObpCloseHandleTableEntry+0xc4 fffff88006275bd0 fffff800028c2153 : fffffa8005575060 fffff88006275ca0 0000000000000000 fffffa800505f2f0 : nt!ObpCloseHandle+0x94 fffff88006275c20 0000000077a0ffaa : 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13 000000001c6bf2d8 0000000000000000 : 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 : 0x77a0ffaa

STACK_COMMAND: kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: nt!ExFreePool+75b fffff800`029f410b cc int 3

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX: 1

SYMBOL_NAME: nt!ExFreePool+75b

FOLLOWUP_NAME: Pool_corruption

IMAGE_NAME: Pool_Corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP: 0

MODULE_NAME: Pool_Corruption

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: X64_0x19_3_nt!ExFreePool+75b

BUCKET_ID: X64_0x19_3_nt!ExFreePool+75b

Followup: Pool_corruption

kd> !analyze -v

*
Bugcheck Analysis *
*
MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a) # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined. Arguments: Arg1: 0000000000041790, The subtype of the bugcheck. Arg2: fffffa8000914760 Arg3: 000000000000ffff Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:

BUGCHECK_STR: 0x1a_41790

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT: 1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID: VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME: chrome.exe

CURRENT_IRQL: 0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER: from fffff8000294326e to fffff800028d0f00

STACK_TEXT:
fffff8800816b828 fffff8000294326e : 000000000000001a 0000000000041790 fffffa8000914760 000000000000ffff : nt!KeBugCheckEx fffff8800816b830 fffff800029045d9 : 0000000000000000 000000000d688fff fffff88000000000 fffffa8000000000 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::string'+0x339d6 fffff8800816b9f0 fffff80002be6e50 : fffffa8005960e30 0007ffff00000000 fffffa80055a9090 fffffa80055a9090 : nt!MiRemoveMappedView+0xd9 fffff8800816bb10 fffff80002be725b : 0000098000000000 000000000d530000 fffffa8000000001 000000000025ec01 : nt!MiUnmapViewOfSection+0x1b0 fffff8800816bbd0 fffff800028d0153 : 0000000000000000 000000000a1d3a14 fffffa8005a08430 0000000000000004 : nt!NtUnmapViewOfSection+0x5f fffff8800816bc20 0000000076da015a : 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13 000000000025e2d8 0000000000000000 : 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x76da015a

STACK_COMMAND: kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::string'+339d6 fffff8000294326e cc int 3

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX: 1

SYMBOL_NAME: nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+339d6

FOLLOWUP_NAME: MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME: ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP: 4a5bc600

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: X64_0x1a_41790_nt!??::FNODOBFM::string+339d6

BUCKET_ID: X64_0x1a_41790_nt!??::FNODOBFM::string+339d6

Followup: MachineOwner



3: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041790, The subtype of the bugcheck.
Arg2: fffffa8003d8a3b0
Arg3: 000000000000ffff
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_41790

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800028ea26e to fffff80002877f00

STACK_TEXT:
fffff880`084be968 fffff800`028ea26e : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00041790 fffffa
80`03d8a3b0 00000000`0000ffff : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`084be970 fffff800`028b9c4a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`1d86ffff fffffa
80`00000000 fffffa80`07375730 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x339d6
fffff880`084beb30 fffff800`02877153 : ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`0428f248 000000
00`0428f240 00000000`00008000 : nt!NtFreeVirtualMemory+0x5ca
fffff880`084bec20 00000000`7765009a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000000
00`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`0428f208 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000000
00`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x7765009a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP:
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+339d6
fffff800`028ea26e cc              int     3

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+339d6

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bc600

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1a_41790_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_+339d6

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1a_41790_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_+339d6

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

3: kd>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [Microsoft employee](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/68407ce1-7491-4aee-bdef-5ff4bbc56d99/#11ce9f45-7906-4652-9619-a3ad457a87e9) error code 41790 with [Bug Check 0x1A: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) means you have RAM issues:

> The 41790 code is part of our an internal memory manager code but the
>   bugcheck in my experience has almost always indicated hardware issues
>   (RAM errors).

Please download [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/download/5.01/), burn a new bootable CD (use a CD-RW if possible) from the ISO (download and use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download) to do this or make double click on the ISO in Windows 7), reboot your PC and scan your RAM 4-5hours for errors. If memtest86+ detects errors, test each module its own and replace the faulty RAM.

If the memtest tells no error, please download [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), look in the memory and SPD tab and verify that the current RAM Speed and the Timings match to the values that you see in the SPD tab. If your RAM run at CR (Command Rate) 1T, change the value into 2T in the BIOS.